# ADFS 3.0 and invalid JWT

Tags: oauth, jwt, adfs

ADFS 3.0 = Windows Server 2012 R2.

Up until now we've only set up SAML authentications, but now a client requested for OAuth2 specifically. Since we didn't have earlier implementations to reference, I googled up articles about how to set up OAuth2 on ADFS 3.0. [I used this article](http://www.gi-architects.co.uk/2016/04/setup-oauth2-on-adfs-3-0/) as reference.

Then I send the clientID, auth and token endpoints to the client. I also mention that the client should be able to get the public keys from our FederationMetadata.xml file.

Our client can get the token without any issues, but complains that the JWT header is invalid. What they get back is "https://.../auth_oauth/microsoft/signin?code=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA-..." and apparently that "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" part is what is supposedly invalid.

And since googling didn't turn up any hints about how to solve this problem, I am kinda stumped. I am by no means ADFS expert, I started fiddling with it only last week.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Normally I do this with PowerShell as per [this](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/).

This uses "Add-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust".

Note that in ADFS 3.0, only OAuth2 API support is enabled.

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at the article. There does not seem to be any differences to the article I used, except that cloudidentity.com article is missing the EnableJWT part. I don't know whether that is even required though. But still, I've decided to delete old trust and create a new one from scratch to see if that helps at all. I'll update with results.

Answer (score 0):

There was no problem after all. The returned code tag is used to retrieve access_token, which is the valid JWT.